# Atom: Unstaged Changes Pop Up

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using the Atom IDE, and an "Unstaged Changes" tab pops up each time I switch to an other tab (see image below).

I know what unstaged changes are, I just don't know how to keep the window from popping up all the time. I've turned off all the packages that contain the word "git", but that didn't solve the isse. Any help would be appreciated!

[Atom Unstaged Changes Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og4b7.jpg)

Comment: Could you give the whole exact message or a screen shot?

Comment: Wow, I've been using Atom since it exists and same goes for Atom IDE, and I am heavy git user, never seen this before. Are you using git? Are you commiting your changes regularly? If not, try removing `.git` hidden folder from the root directory of the project. If you do use git, make sure your git flow is done properly. (Make sure your code is not behind repo and you pulled/pushed all history code)

Comment: @Gerard, It might help us if you shared the list of packages you have installed. If you can open the command line and use `apm ls` to pull up a full list. Copy it to the paste sharing site of your choice, or gist.github.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Atom, and reinstalled it. That solved the problem. I was hoping to not have to uninstall, but it was really making me crazy to work with the constant pop-ups.

Thanks for all the comments! It seems like it wasn't a problem with the .git file in the project folder (since that wouldn't be effected by reinstalling Atom)